# Simple way to run sklearn function with n_jobs > 1 inside parallel pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, nested-loops

Is there some ways to run sklearn (supporting n_jobs argument) inside parallel loop? When I try to run sklearn function with n_jobs >1 inside multiprocessing.Pool, I've got the warning

```
UserWarning: Multiprocessing-backed parallel loops cannot be nested, setting n_jobs=1
  for s in split_list(seeds, n_jobs))
```

So does exist some parallel library, which allows nested parallelisation?

Answer (score 1):

This Warning comes from `joblib`, the multiprocessing library used in `sklearn`.
It occurs as its parallel mechanism relies on `multiprocessing.Pool` which uses `daemonic` workers that cannot spawn subprocess.

I don't see any simple way to by pass this restriction with `sklearn`.
You might want to create and manage your process by hand.
If you know what you are doing, you could create your `Process` and used them to run `sklearn` functions with `n_jobs > 1`.
This will imply a lot a care managing the process and not running them all at once.
It is also important to not make them `daemonic`.
For instance:

```
def target(j):
    from time import sleep
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2)
    rf.fit(np.random.random(size=(100, 100)), np.random.random(100)> .6)
    print(j, 'done')
pr = [mp.Process(target=target, args=(i,)) for i in range(10)];\
[p.start() for p in pr]
[p.join() for p in pr]
```

Note that all the Processes are run simultaneously and this could lead to worst performance than the sequential implementation.

That being said, their is not much usecases where using nested parallelism is a good idea.
All the core should be used for the task which is the more time consumming, the other tasks running sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still encounters this problem, the last comment of this github [issue](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/978) did the trick for me. Just calling the function `_patch_joblib_loky_backend()` before instantiating the sklearn algorithm, no need for the pragma `with parallel_backend("loky")`, at least in my program. Do not hesitate to ask me for more details if needed. Toodaloo:)